# declaring Nodes in Ns3

Tags: ns-3

I am completely new to NS3, i am tasked to set two eNBs and one UE between them to demonstrate x2 handover, i have successfully set the eNBs and UE and also set a mobility model for the UE, now i wanted to generate an XML trace file to run on the NetAnim, when i added the following line to my code

```
AnimationInterface anim ("x2-handover-animation.xml"); 
anim.SetMobilityPollInterval (Seconds (0.3));
```

it also two extra nodes, giving me a total of 5 node instead of the three (2 eNBs and 1 UE) i declared.

Your kind assistance is solicited.

Below is the extract of my source code

```
#include "ns3/core-module.h"
#include "ns3/network-module.h"
#include "ns3/internet-module.h"
#include "ns3/mobility-module.h"
#include "ns3/lte-module.h"
#include "ns3/applications-module.h"
#include "ns3/point-to-point-module.h"
#include "ns3/config-store-module.h"
#include "ns3/csma-module.h"
#include "ns3/wifi-module.h"
#include "ns3/netanim-module.h"
#include "ns3/mobility-helper.h"
#include "ns3/flow-monitor-module.h"

using namespace ns3;


void 
NotifyConnectionEstablishedUe (std::string context, 
                           uint64_t imsi, 
                           uint16_t cellid, 
                           uint16_t rnti)
{
std::cout << context 
        << " UE IMSI " << imsi 
        << ": connected to CellId " << cellid 
        << " with RNTI " << rnti 
        << std::endl;
}

void 
NotifyHandoverStartUe (std::string context, 
                   uint64_t imsi, 
                   uint16_t cellid, 
                   uint16_t rnti, 
                   uint16_t targetCellId)
{
std::cout << context 
        << " UE IMSI " << imsi 
        << ": previously connected to CellId " << cellid 
        << " with RNTI " << rnti 
        << ", doing handover to CellId " << targetCellId 
        << std::endl;
}

void 
NotifyHandoverEndOkUe (std::string context, 
                   uint64_t imsi, 
                   uint16_t cellid, 
                   uint16_t rnti)
{
  std::cout << context 
        << " UE IMSI " << imsi 
        << ": successful handover to CellId " << cellid 
        << " with RNTI " << rnti 
        << std::endl;
}

void 
NotifyConnectionEstablishedEnb (std::string context, 
                            uint64_t imsi, 
                            uint16_t cellid, 
                            uint16_t rnti)
{
  std::cout << context 
        << " eNB CellId " << cellid 
        << ": successful connection of UE with IMSI " << imsi 
        << " RNTI " << rnti 
        << std::endl;
}

void 
NotifyHandoverStartEnb (std::string context, 
                    uint64_t imsi, 
                    uint16_t cellid, 
                    uint16_t rnti, 
                    uint16_t targetCellId)
{
  std::cout << context 
        << " eNB CellId " << cellid 
        << ": start handover of UE with IMSI " << imsi 
        << " RNTI " << rnti 
        << " to CellId " << targetCellId 
        << std::endl;
}

void 
NotifyHandoverEndOkEnb (std::string context, 
                    uint64_t imsi, 
                    uint16_t cellid, 
                    uint16_t rnti)
{
  std::cout << context 
        << " eNB CellId " << cellid 
        << ": completed handover of UE with IMSI " << imsi 
        << " RNTI " << rnti 
        << std::endl;
}




/**
 * Sample simulation script for a X2-based handover.
 * It instantiates two eNodeB, attaches one UE to the 'source' eNB and
 * triggers a handover of the UE towards the 'target' eNB.
 */
 NS_LOG_COMPONENT_DEFINE ("EpcX2HandoverExample");

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

uint16_t numberOfUes = 1; // the 1 Ue i declared
uint16_t numberOfEnbs = 2; // the 2 ENBs i declared
uint16_t numBearersPerUe = 0;
double simTime = 10.00;


// change some default attributes so that they are reasonable for
// this scenario, but do this before processing command line
// arguments, so that the user is allowed to override these settings 
Config::SetDefault ("ns3::UdpClient::Interval", TimeValue (MilliSeconds(10)));
Config::SetDefault ("ns3::UdpClient::MaxPackets", UintegerValue(1000000));
Config::SetDefault ("ns3::LteHelper::UseIdealRrc", BooleanValue(false));

  // Command line arguments
 CommandLine cmd;
 cmd.AddValue("numberOfUes", "Number of UEs", numberOfUes);
 cmd.AddValue("numberOfEnbs", "Number of eNodeBs", numberOfEnbs);
 cmd.AddValue("simTime", "Total duration of the simulation (in seconds)",simTime);
  cmd.Parse(argc, argv);


  Ptr<LteHelper> lteHelper = CreateObject<LteHelper> ();
  Ptr<EpcHelper> epcHelper = CreateObject<EpcHelper> ();
  lteHelper->SetEpcHelper (epcHelper);
  lteHelper->SetSchedulerType("ns3::RrFfMacScheduler");

  Ptr<Node> pgw = epcHelper->GetPgwNode ();

  // Create a single RemoteHost
  NodeContainer remoteHostContainer;
  remoteHostContainer.Create (1);
  Ptr<Node> remoteHost = remoteHostContainer.Get (0);
  InternetStackHelper internet;
  internet.Install (remoteHostContainer);

  // Create the Internet
  PointToPointHelper p2ph;
  p2ph.SetDeviceAttribute ("DataRate", DataRateValue (DataRate ("100Gb/s")));
  p2ph.SetDeviceAttribute ("Mtu", UintegerValue (1500));
  p2ph.SetChannelAttribute ("Delay", TimeValue (Seconds (0.010)));
  NetDeviceContainer internetDevices = p2ph.Install (pgw, remoteHost);
  Ipv4AddressHelper ipv4h;
  ipv4h.SetBase ("1.0.0.0", "255.0.0.0");
  Ipv4InterfaceContainer internetIpIfaces = ipv4h.Assign (internetDevices);
  Ipv4Address remoteHostAddr = internetIpIfaces.GetAddress (1);


  // Routing of the Internet Host (towards the LTE network)
  Ipv4StaticRoutingHelper ipv4RoutingHelper;
  Ptr<Ipv4StaticRouting> remoteHostStaticRouting =pv4RoutingHelper.GetStaticRouting     (remoteHost->GetObject<Ipv4> ());
  // interface 0 is localhost, 1 is the p2p device
  remoteHostStaticRouting->AddNetworkRouteTo (Ipv4Address ("7.0.0.0"), Ipv4Mask    ("255.0.0.0"), 1);

  NodeContainer ueNodes;
  NodeContainer enbNodes;
  enbNodes.Create(numberOfEnbs);
  ueNodes.Create(numberOfUes);


 AnimationInterface anim ("x2-handover-animation.xml"); //code i added to generate XML file 
 anim.SetMobilityPollInterval (Seconds (0.3));

 MobilityHelper mobility;

   mobility.SetMobilityModel ("ns3::RandomDirection2dMobilityModel",
                         "Bounds", RectangleValue (Rectangle (-50, 50, -50, 50)));
  mobility.Install (ueNodes);
  mobility.SetMobilityModel ("ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel");
  mobility.Install (enbNodes);

  // Install LTE Devices in eNB and UEs
  NetDeviceContainer enbLteDevs = lteHelper->InstallEnbDevice (enbNodes);
  NetDeviceContainer ueLteDevs = lteHelper->InstallUeDevice (ueNodes);

  // Install the IP stack on the UEs
  internet.Install (ueNodes);
  Ipv4InterfaceContainer ueIpIfaces;
  ueIpIfaces = epcHelper->AssignUeIpv4Address (NetDeviceContainer (ueLteDevs));
  // Assign IP address to UEs, and install applications
  for (uint32_t u = 0; u < ueNodes.GetN (); ++u)

    {
      Ptr<Node> ueNode = ueNodes.Get (u);
      // Set the default gateway for the UE
      Ptr<Ipv4StaticRouting> ueStaticRouting = ipv4RoutingHelper.GetStaticRouting  (ueNode->GetObject<Ipv4> ());
      ueStaticRouting->SetDefaultRoute (epcHelper->GetUeDefaultGatewayAddress (), 1);
    }


  // Attach all UEs to the first eNodeB
  for (uint16_t i = 0; i < numberOfUes; i++)

    {
      lteHelper->Attach (ueLteDevs.Get(i), enbLteDevs.Get(0));
    }


  NS_LOG_LOGIC ("setting up applications");

  // Install and start applications on UEs and remote host
  uint16_t dlPort = 10000;
  uint16_t ulPort = 20000;

  // randomize a bit start times to avoid simulation artifacts
  // (e.g., buffer overflows due to packet transmissions happening
  // exactly at the same time) 
  Ptr<UniformRandomVariable> startTimeSeconds = CreateObject<UniformRandomVariable> ();
  startTimeSeconds->SetAttribute ("Min", DoubleValue (0));
  startTimeSeconds->SetAttribute ("Max", DoubleValue (0.010));

    for (uint32_t u = 0; u < numberOfUes; ++u)
    {
      Ptr<Node> ue = ueNodes.Get (u);
      // Set the default gateway for the UE
      Ptr<Ipv4StaticRouting> ueStaticRouting = ipv4RoutingHelper.GetStaticRouting (ue->GetObject<Ipv4> ());
      ueStaticRouting->SetDefaultRoute (epcHelper->GetUeDefaultGatewayAddress (), 1);

      for (uint32_t b = 0; b < numBearersPerUe; ++b)

    {
       ++dlPort;
      ++ulPort;

      ApplicationContainer clientApps;
      ApplicationContainer serverApps;

      NS_LOG_LOGIC ("installing UDP DL app for UE " << u);
      UdpClientHelper dlClientHelper (ueIpIfaces.GetAddress (u), dlPort);
      clientApps.Add (dlClientHelper.Install (remoteHost));
      PacketSinkHelper dlPacketSinkHelper ("ns3::UdpSocketFactory", 
                                           InetSocketAddress (Ipv4Address::GetAny (), dlPort));
      serverApps.Add (dlPacketSinkHelper.Install (ue));

      NS_LOG_LOGIC ("installing UDP UL app for UE " << u);
      UdpClientHelper ulClientHelper (remoteHostAddr, ulPort);
      clientApps.Add (ulClientHelper.Install (ue));
      PacketSinkHelper ulPacketSinkHelper ("ns3::UdpSocketFactory", 
                                           InetSocketAddress (Ipv4Address::GetAny (), ulPort));
      serverApps.Add (ulPacketSinkHelper.Install (remoteHost));  

      Ptr<EpcTft> tft = Create<EpcTft> ();
      EpcTft::PacketFilter dlpf;
      dlpf.localPortStart = dlPort;
      dlpf.localPortEnd = dlPort;
      tft->Add (dlpf); 
      EpcTft::PacketFilter ulpf;
      ulpf.remotePortStart = ulPort;
      ulpf.remotePortEnd = ulPort;
      tft->Add (ulpf);
      EpsBearer bearer (EpsBearer::NGBR_VIDEO_TCP_DEFAULT);
      lteHelper->ActivateDedicatedEpsBearer (ueLteDevs.Get (u), bearer, tft);

      Time startTime = Seconds (startTimeSeconds->GetValue ());
      serverApps.Start (startTime);
      clientApps.Start (startTime);

    } // end for b
    }


  // Add X2 inteface
  lteHelper->AddX2Interface (enbNodes);

  // X2-based Handover
  lteHelper->HandoverRequest (Seconds (0.100), ueLteDevs.Get (0), enbLteDevs.Get (0),  enbLteDevs.Get (1));


  // Uncomment to enable PCAP tracing
  p2ph.EnablePcapAll("lena-x2-handover");

  lteHelper->EnableMacTraces ();
  lteHelper->EnableRlcTraces ();
  lteHelper->EnablePdcpTraces ();
  Ptr<RadioBearerStatsCalculator> rlcStats = lteHelper->GetRlcStats ();
  rlcStats->SetAttribute ("EpochDuration", TimeValue (Seconds (0.05)));
  Ptr<RadioBearerStatsCalculator> pdcpStats = lteHelper->GetPdcpStats ();
  pdcpStats->SetAttribute ("EpochDuration", TimeValue (Seconds (0.05)));


  // connect custom trace sinks for RRC connection establishment and handover    notification
  Config::Connect ("/NodeList/*/DeviceList/*/LteEnbRrc/ConnectionEstablished",
               MakeCallback (&NotifyConnectionEstablishedEnb));
  Config::Connect ("/NodeList/*/DeviceList/*/LteUeRrc/ConnectionEstablished",
               MakeCallback (&NotifyConnectionEstablishedUe));
  Config::Connect ("/NodeList/*/DeviceList/*/LteEnbRrc/HandoverStart",
               MakeCallback (&NotifyHandoverStartEnb));
  Config::Connect ("/NodeList/*/DeviceList/*/LteUeRrc/HandoverStart",
               MakeCallback (&NotifyHandoverStartUe));
  Config::Connect ("/NodeList/*/DeviceList/*/LteEnbRrc/HandoverEndOk",
               MakeCallback (&NotifyHandoverEndOkEnb));
  Config::Connect ("/NodeList/*/DeviceList/*/LteUeRrc/HandoverEndOk",
               MakeCallback (&NotifyHandoverEndOkUe));


  Simulator::Stop(Seconds(simTime));
  Simulator::Run();

  // GtkConfigStore config;
  // config.ConfigureAttributes();

  Simulator::Destroy();
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As I see in this code you have created 5 Nodes not 3.

The First one is pgw node which is and EPC entity

```
Ptr<Node> pgw = epcHelper->GetPgwNode ();
```

The Second one is a remote host

```
remoteHostContainer.Create (1);
```

These two nodes are connected point to point using the following code

```
NetDeviceContainer internetDevices = p2ph.Install (pgw, remoteHost);
```

The third and fourth nodes are the ENB Nodes "numberOfEnbs = 2;"

```
enbNodes.Create(numberOfEnbs);
```

The fifth is the Ue node "numberOfUes = 1;"

```
 ueNodes.Create(numberOfUes);
```

Thus you should have 5 nodes not three :)

The first two nodes represents the Internet connection that is connected to the LTE network that you created. While the last 3 nodes represents your LTE Network.